# Trying to pass the value of a label but receiving an error 'Cannot assign value of type 'Organizations?' to type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a tableview where once a tableview cell is selected, it passes the name of the cell to a new view controller. However, when trying to change the organizationName I receive the error, 'Cannot assign value of type 'Organizations?' to type 'String'. How do I fix this so that the rowTitle of the tableview cell is then displayed as the organizationName on the next viewController?

Here is my code for the first view controller.

```
import UIKit

struct Organizations {
var sectionTitle = String()
var rowTitles = [String]()
}

class SearchOrganizationsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var searchOrganizations: Organizations?
var organizations = [Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2", "organization 3"]),
    Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2"]),
    Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["organization 1"])
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

extension SearchOrganizationsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
if searching {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
} else {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = self.organizations[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
}
return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
selectedOrganizations = organizations[indexPath.row]
performSegue(withIdentifier: "organizationDetailSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let destination = segue.destination as? OrganizationsDetailViewController {
    destination.organization = selectedOrganizations 
}
}

}
```

Here is my code for the second view controller.

```
import UIKit

class OrganizationsDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var organizationNameLabel: UILabel!

var organization: Organizations? = nil {
    didSet { self.organizationNameLabel.text = organization?.sectionTitle}
} // error is here

var organizationName: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

organizationNameLabel.text = organizationName
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you why. You’re trying to assign the organization to the variable that wants a string.

You want to assign it to the actual `organization` inside the `detailController`

Or assign the string value to one of the row titles or whatever value you want to show.

```
organizationName = selectedOrganization.rowTitles[indexPath.row]
```

For a cleaner detail I would use the `didSet`option inside your detail view controller

```
Class DetailViewController:UIViewController {
  var organization:Organizations? = nil 
  var selectedRow: Int = 0

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLabel()
  }

  private func setupLabel() {
    guard let org = self.organization else { 
      print(“no organization set”)
      return 
    }
    self.organizationLabel.text = org.rowTitles[selectedRow]
  }
}
```

Then in your tableView VC I would just assign the selected organization to the variable in the detail

So you could add another variable that holds the selected row alongside your selectedOrganization in your tableView controller in your `didSelectRow` func, set the variable to the selected row and you should be good to go

```
var selectedRow = 0


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if let destination = segue.destination as? OrganizationsDetailViewController {
    destination.organization= selectedOrganizations
    destination.selectedRow = selectedRow
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the didSet and changed the assignment of the selected organization, but when I run it and click on a cell, I receive the error, 'Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value'.

Comment: Are you force unwrapping anything? Is your selected organization being written to?

Comment: You also should be able to remove the organizationName string value from the detail, as you would be able to access it from the organization variable in the detail

Comment: Okay, quick search shows that IBOutlets return nil during the prepareForSegue function. I’ll edit my answer now

Comment: There are no more errors, but when I run it, it doesn't display anything for the organization name.

Comment: Okay, set a breakpoint on the guard statement to see if it is being called

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the guard and received this 'Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1' when clicking on a cell.

Comment: So it is being called. Is there a value inside the organization variable?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: So, I’ve edited the answer to give you a little print check

Comment: No statement is printed out.

Comment: So, what if you set it to some arbitrary value, does it appear on your screen

Comment: Does your viewDidLoad still have the organizationLabel.text = organizationName?

Comment: Not anymore. It is displaying now but the section Titles and not the row Titles. How do I change this?

Comment: The rowTitles for each section.

Comment: You want to display all of them? In a list, or just the rowTitle that was tapped?

Comment: just the rowTitle that was tapped.

Comment: Edited answer. See if that helps

Comment: Thanks. This is closer but when I select "organization 2" from the section "section 1", I receive the text of "organization 1" of "section 2".

Comment: When you set the selectedOrganization in the didSelectRow make sure you are setting it to the indexPath.section not indexPath.row

Comment: No problem, glad we got you to the finish line